# Another iOS7 UIButton not working issue

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview

I've read several posts related to this issue where a UIButton is not responding/triggering within iOS 7, but can't find the solution. Here's the general layout for my app... I have a collectionview of images and tapping a cell/image brings up a new UIImageView to display the image in fullscreen. This fullscreen imageview is created in code, but the collectionview is storyboarded. A UIButton is programmatically added to the fullscreen imageview that comes up after tapping the cell/image. While in the fullscreen imageview mode, tapping the imageview again makes it disappear and go back to the collectionview view...all works with no issues. The issue is the button on the fullscreen imageview. It's visible but will not trigger. I've added NSLog to the method that gets called and I never see it. I've done all sorts of things mentioned in the various threads and nothing works.

However, one thing I did come across that did work was setting the fullscreen imageview's setUserInteractionEnabled=YES. While that did start triggering the button, it had a side effect of no longer allowing the fullscreen imageview to go away when tapping. In other words, I couldn't go back to the collectionview view, I was stuck in the fullscreen view. I know I could probably add another button to manually close, but that seems like a hack.

From all the reading I've done, it seems clear that my issue is the result of some type of parent/container view and bounds issue, where the button is technically outside of some bounds and is therefore not able to receive the message. However, I cannot get a clear enough understanding of this to fix it. So hopefully, I can post my code here and someone can provide a clear example of what I need to do. Thanks in advance!!!

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ViewCell *selectedCell = (ViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"didSelectItemAtIndexPath");
    self.fullScreenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, self.view.bounds.size.height-15)];
    self.fullScreenImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.fullScreenImage.tag = 1;
    /** REQUIRED for likeButton to work. Otherwise, button is visible but doesn't respond */
    //[self.fullScreenImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    CGFloat xCoord = self.fullScreenImage.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat yCoord = self.fullScreenImage.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat yPoint = self.fullScreenImage.bounds.origin.y;

    UIButton *likeButton = [[UIButton alloc] init]; // button for liking image and storing in profile
    likeButton.tag = indexPath.row; // set the tag of the button to the indexpath.row so we know which cell/image is selected

    [likeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord - xCoord, yPoint + (yCoord-LIKE_BUTTON_HEIGHT), LIKE_BUTTON_WIDTH, LIKE_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart_blue"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // this will be NO if coming from collection view
    if (!self.isFullScreen) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            NSLog(@"Starting animiation!")

            // hide the following uiview items so they will not be visible or active
            self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
            self.toolBar.hidden = YES;
            self.imageRecipeSegmentedControl.hidden = YES;
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
            self.fullScreenImage.center = self.view.center;
            self.fullScreenImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.fullScreenImage.image = selectedCell.imageView.image;
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [self.view addSubview:self.fullScreenImage];
            [self.fullScreenImage addSubview:likeButton]; // add the button to the view
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [self.fullScreenImage bringSubviewToFront:likeButton];
            self.isFullScreen = YES;
        }];
        return;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Ending animiation!");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.62 green:0.651 blue:0.686 alpha:1];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
            self.searchBar.hidden = NO;
            self.toolBar.hidden = NO;
            self.imageRecipeSegmentedControl.hidden = NO;
            // loop through to remove the correct view from the superview
            for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
                if (subView.tag == (int)self.fullScreenImage.tag) {
                    [subView removeFromSuperview];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            self.isFullScreen = NO;
        }];
        return;
    }
}
```